# Relating Heisenberg and Schrodinger Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation

So in the [Heisenberg picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) operators evolve with time but the wave functions stay constant in time and in the [Schrodinger picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture) the wave function evolves with time. This statement makes sense to me such that

$\langle{\psi_t}|O_s|\psi_t\rangle=\langle{\psi}|O_H(t)|\psi\rangle\tag{1}$

Where $O_s$ and $O_H(t)$ are observables.

$\hat{H}^H=k\hat{S}_z^H=k\hat{S}_z  \tag{2}$

(2) here is found when a spin-1/2 particle is at rest in a magnetic field $\overrightarrow{B}=B\overrightarrow{e}_z$ the particle has a Hamiltonain

$\hat{H}=k\hat{S}_z\tag{3}$

How is (2) true? Is there some basic understanding I have missed the only idea I had was that $\hat{S}_z=m_z\hbar$ which isn't time dependant so $\hat{S}_z^H=\hat{S}_z$ but aside this I can't explain why the relation in (2) is true and how to derive it.

Ok so using the answer given by @ZeroTheHero I have

$\hat{H}^H=e^{\frac{iHt}{\hbar}}\hat{H}^s e^{-\frac{iHt}{\hbar}}=e^{\frac{iHt}{\hbar}}(k\hat{S}_z)e^{-\frac{iHt}{\hbar}}=k\hat{S}_z\tag{4}$

How would I then find $\hat{S}_x^H$ and $\hat{S}_x^H$?

Answer (score 5):

Operators in both formulations are related by $U(t)=e^{-iHt/\hbar}$.  Specifically,
$$
\hat O_H=e^{iHt/\hbar}\hat O_S e^{-iHt/\hbar}\, .
$$
In particular, the Hamiltonian 
$$
\hat H_H=e^{iHt/\hbar}\hat H_S e^{-iHt/\hbar}=\hat H_S\, .
$$

---

Edit: to obtain - say - $S^H_x$, use
$$
e^{-i\sigma_z t/2}\sigma_x e^{i\sigma_z t/2}=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0&e^{it}\\
e^{-it}&0\\
\end{array}\right) = \hat \sigma^{S}_x \cos(t)- \hat \sigma^{S}_y\sin(t)\, .
$$
Since the result does not depend on the representation $j$, we thus find
$$
\hat S_x^H = \hat S_x^S \cos(t)-\hat S_y^S\sin(t)\, .
$$